# JQUERY image upload form and css issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am currently working with an image uploader. I am having difficulties maneuvering with jquery/css. I am needing help in getting the remove button to appear beside the thumb image that has been rendered. Also, is there a way i can replace this with the famous [x] that also indicates remove? I am using an example from this [SITE](http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer/)

Picture:
[image]

**Jquery**

```
<script>
    function createImageForm(index) {

        var form = '';

        form += '<div><table cellspacing="0">';
        form += '<tr><td class="label">'
              + '<label for="imageToUpload' + index + '">'
              + $.uploaderPreviewer.messages.imageLabel + ' ' + index + ':</label></td>';
        form += '<td class="removeImageButton">'
              + '<button class="small removeImage" /></td>';
        form += '<td class="imageFormFileField">'
              // BUG: If the "enctype" attribute is assigned with jQuery, IE crashes
              + '<form enctype="multipart/form-data">'
              + '<input id="imageToUpload' + index + '" type="file" />'
              + '<input type="hidden" name="currentUploadedFilename"'
              + ' class="currentUploadedFilename" /></form>'
              + '</td></tr>';
        form += '<tr><td></td><td></td><td>'
              + '<div class="previewImage"><img /></div>'
              + '</td></tr></table></div>';

        return form;
    };
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
button.small {
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 50px;
}

.imageForms td.removeImageButton {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70px;
}
```

Comment: With your current code based on tables it's going to be a challenge.

Comment: Let's all [stop using table based design](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code.

function createImageForm(index) {

```
    var form = '';

    form += '<div><table cellspacing="0">';
    form += '<tr><td class="label">'
          + '<label for="imageToUpload' + index + '">'
          + $.uploaderPreviewer.messages.imageLabel + ' ' + index + ':</label></td>';
    form += '<td class="removeImageButton">'
          + '</td>';
    form += '<td class="imageFormFileField">'
          // BUG: If the "enctype" attribute is assigned with jQuery, IE crashes
          + '<form enctype="multipart/form-data">'
          + '<input id="imageToUpload' + index + '" type="file" />'
          + '<input type="hidden" name="currentUploadedFilename"'
          + ' class="currentUploadedFilename" /></form>'
          + '</td></tr>';
    form += '<tr><td></td><td></td><td>'
          + '<div class="previewImage" style="float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0"><img /></div>'
          + '<button class="small removeImage" /></td></tr></table></div>';

    return form;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, This is perfect. Do you think there will be a possibility of replacing that remove button with something like [x] that will indicate delete?

Comment: Yes, you can replace remove button, You can use what you like and call remove function which currently you are using for removing image.